# Wait until a time-consuming function finishes

Tags: ms-office, office-js

In the execution of my add-in, there is a function which may take around 15 seconds to run (in the worst case). I realise that in Excel Online, the system will wait until the function finishes. However, in Excel Windows, several seconds later, the system considers the add-in does not respond, and restarts the add-in:

[image]

I have made a time-consuming function as follows, which is not my initial function. The test under Excel Windows shows that after clicking on the `test` button, nothing is printed in the text area, several seconds later, the system restarts the add-in.

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    Office.initialize = function(reason) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            app.initialize();
            $('#test').click(test)
        });
    };

    function test() {
        document.getElementById("b").value += 'Start\n';
        var x = 10000;
        var w = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            document.getElementById("b").value += i + '\n';
            for (var j = 0; j < x; j++) {
                for (var k = 0; k < x; k++) {
                    w = w + 1;
                    w = w - 1;
                }
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("b").value += 'End\n';
    }   
})();
```

Does anyone know how to let the system wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no different than you would need to do in a regular website.  See the excellent article here (https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/13/speed-up-your-javascript-part-1/), especially the section about chunking and using setTimeout.